# Doubling all occurrences of a specific character in a string

Tags: c, duplicates, char, c-strings, function-definition

I want to write a C program, that returns a new string allocated on the heap. This string is obtained by doubling all occurrences of “c” in a string (“abcdc” becomes “abccdcc” after doubling “c”).

This is my code and I don't really see where the problem is to fix it!

```
    size_t taille = stringLength(str);
    size_t k=0;
    size_t q=0;
    
    while (*str!='\0') 
    {
        if (*str == c)
        {
            k=k+1;
        }
        ++str;
    }
    
    char *nouvelle=malloc(taille+1+k);
    
    int i,j= 0;
    while(*str !='\0')
    {
        
        if (str[i] != c)
        {
            j=i;
            nouvelle[j]=str[i];
        }
        else
        {
            j=i;
            ++q;
            nouvelle[j]=str[i];
            j=i+q;
            nouvelle[j++]=str[i];
            
        }
        ++i;
    }
    nouvelle[taille+1+k]='\0';
    return nouvelle;
}
```

Comment: Welcome, please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. May I also suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is `stringLength`? If you can use `malloc` why can't you use `strlen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first one is that after this while loop

```
while (*str!='\0') 
{
    if (*str == c)
    {
        k=k+1;
    }
    ++str;
}
```

the pointer `str` points to the end of the string that is to the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

The second one is that you are using the uninitialized variable `i`

```
int i,j= 0;
while(*str !='\0')
{
    
    if (str[i] != c)
    {
        j=i;
        //..
```

This declaration

```
int i,j= 0;
```

is not the same as

```
int i = 0,j= 0;
```

That is only the variable j is initialized by 0.

And the statement

```
j = i;
```

does not make sense.

Also it is unclear whether `c` denotes a variable or the character `'c'`. If you mean the character `'c'` then you need to write at least like

```
if (*str == 'c')
```

You could define the function for example the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * duplicate_char( const char *s, char c )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for (const char *p = s; *p; ++p)
    {
        if (*p == c) ++n;
    }

    char *nouvelle = malloc( strlen( s ) + n + 1 );

    if (nouvelle)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            strcpy( nouvelle, s );
        }
        else
        {
            char *p = nouvelle;

            while (*s)
            {
                *p++ = *s++;

                if (p[-1] == c) *p++ = c;
            }

            *p = '\0';
        }
    }

    return nouvelle;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *nouvelle = duplicate_char( "abcdc", 'c' );

    if (nouvelle != NULL) puts( nouvelle );

    free( nouvelle );
}
```

The program output is

```
abccdcc
```

If you want to use your own function `stringLength` instead of the standard C function `strlen` then it can look like

```
size_t stringLength( const char *s )
{
    const char *p = s;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    return p - s;
}
```

Comment: Also `c` should be `'c'`.

Comment: @WeatherVane From the presented code it is not clear whether he means a variable with the name c or the character 'c'.:)

Comment: It is clear from the question description that OP has confused it. The bigger problem is no MCVE.